# Pandas split one dataframe into multiple dataframes

Tags: pandas

I have one pandas dataframe that I need to split into multiple dataframes. The number of dataframes I need to split depends on how many months of data I have i.e I need to create a new dataframe for every month.
So df:

```
MONTH   NAME INCOME
201801   A     100$
201801   B      20$
201802   A      30$
```

So I need to create 2 dataframes . Problem is i dont know how many months of data I will have in advance.
How do i do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use groupby to create a dictionary of data frames,

```
df['MONTH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MONTH'], format = '%Y%m')
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['MONTH'].dt.month)))
dfs[1]


    MONTH   NAME    INCOME
0   2018-01-01  A   100$
1   2018-01-01  B   20$
```

If your data is across multiple years, you will need to include year in the grouping

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby([df['MONTH'].dt.year,df['MONTH'].dt.month])))
dfs[(2018, 1)]

    MONTH      NAME INCOME
0   2018-01-01  A   100$
1   2018-01-01  B   20$
```

Comment: I like your dict(tuple(groupby...).  +1  I'm adding that to my toolbox.

Comment: Thank you. Despite specifying the format = '%Y%m', why did MONTH change from 201801 to 2018-01-01?

Comment: @Victor, Pandas creates date in Ymd format, if date component is missing, it will add 01 as the date.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `groupby` to split dataframes in to list of dataframes or a dictionary of datframes:

Dictionary of dataframes:

```
dict_of_dfs = {}
for n, g in df.groupby(df['MONTH']):
    dict_of_dfs[n] = g
```

List of dataframes:

```
list_of_dfs = []
for _, g in df.groupby(df['MONTH']):
    list_of_dfs.append(g)
```

Or as @BenMares suggests use comprehension:

```
dict_of_dfs = {

    month: group_df 

    for month, group_df in df.groupby('MONTH') 

}


list_of_dfs = [

    group_df 

    for _, group_df in df.groupby('MONTH')

]
```

Comment: It would be much more elegant to use a comprehension! `{index: group_df for index, group_df in df.groupby('MONTH')}`

Comment: Agreed dictionary comprehension.  Nice, @BenMares.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use local variable dictionary vars() in this way:

```
for m in df['MONTH'].unique():
    temp = 'df_{}'.format(m)    
    vars()[temp] = df[df['MONTH']==m]
```

each DataFrame is created as under name df_month. For example:

**df_201801**

```
    MONTH   NAME    INCOME
0   201801  A   100$
1   201801  B   20$
```