# How to save multiple dataframes saved in a dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Continuing from the post that I'll link below, the answer provides how to split a data frame into the number of months the df has (i.e if a dataframe has 6 months, then you'll get 6 dataframes, one for each month). What I want to know is a generic code, such as a for loop to save those dataframes as csv files.

[Pandas split one dataframe into multiple dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54046707/pandas-split-one-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes)

I used the second solution to split my df because it spans more than one year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This  will grab each df from your dictionary (the value) and save it to a csv who's file name is the key from the dictionary + '.csv'. Is that what you're looking for?

```
for key, df in df_dict.items():
    df.to_csv(key+'.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks for help, this is what I'm looking for but I'm getting an error -> 'TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple'

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
for key in dfs.iterkeys():
    dfs[key].to_csv("C:/", 'df' + key + '.csv')
```